# Creation of a programming language

Tags: python, parsing, lexer

I have several classes for a Programming Language.

Class Lexer:

```
from rply import LexerGenerator

class Lexer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lexer = LexerGenerator()

    def _add_token(self):
        self.lexer.add('PRINT', r'print')
        self.lexer.add('OPEN_PAREN', r'\(')
        self.lexer.add('CLOSE_PAREN', r'\)')
        self.lexer.add('SEMI_COLON', r'\;')
        self.lexer.add('SUM', r'\+')
        self.lexer.add('SUB', r'\-')
        self.lexer.add('NUMBER', r'\d+')
        self.lexer.ignore('\s+')

    def get_lexer(self):
        self._add_token()
        return self.lexer.build()
```

Class Parser:

```
from rply import ParserGenerator
from ast import Number, Sum, Sub, Print

class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pg = ParserGenerator(
            # Список всех токенов, принятых парсером.
            ['NUMBER', 'PRINT', 'OPEN_PAREN', 'CLOSE_PAREN',
             'SEMI_COLON', 'SUM', 'SUB']
        )

    def parse(self):
        @self.pg.production('program : PRINT OPEN_PAREN expression CLOSE_PAREN SEMI_COLON')
        def program(p):
            return Print(p[2])

        @self.pg.production('expression : expression SUM expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression SUB expression')
        def expression(p):
            left = p[0]
            right = p[2]
            operator = p[1]
            if operator.gettokentype() == 'SUM':
                return Sum(left, right)
            elif operator.gettokentype() == 'SUB':
                return Sub(left, right)

        @self.pg.production('expression : NUMBER')
        def number(p):
            return Number(p[0].value)

        @self.pg.error
        def error_handle(token):
            raise ValueError(token)

    def get_parser(self):
        return self.pg.build()
```

AST:

```
class Number():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return int(self.value)


class BinaryOp():
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class Sum(BinaryOp):
    def eval(self):
        return self.left.eval() + self.right.eval()


class Sub(BinaryOp):
    def eval(self):
        return self.left.eval() - self.right.eval()


class Print():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        print(self.value.eval())
```

And the main file from which everything works.

```
from Lexer import Lexer
from Parser import Parser

text_input = """
print(4 + 4 - 2);
"""

lexer = Lexer().get_lexer()
tokens = lexer.lex(text_input)

pg = Parser()
pg.parse()
parser = pg.get_parser()
parser.parse(tokens).eval()
```

The error occurs when the code is run. However, it gives the correct result.
Line of code print(4 + 4 -2); gives the correct answer 6 and then an error

ParserGeneratorWarning: 4 shift/reduce conflicts
return self.pg.build()

Is it possible to fix it somehow or just ignore it somehow so that there is only an answer.

Anyone who can help, thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Code in message

Comment: Indeed there is code, but a minimal reproducible example should be provided for users to help you. Most people (to not say all) will not even look at the question because there is a lot of irrelevant code in it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that it's not possible to determine which rule should apply first `SUB` or `ADD`. To disambiguate you have to specify `precedence` rules in the `ParserGenerator` (which is in the documentation). Full working example:

```py
from rply import LexerGenerator, ParserGenerator, Token
from rply.lexer import LexerStream
from rply.token import BaseBox


class Lexer:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Create a lexer
        lexer = LexerGenerator()

        # Add elements
        lexer.add("FLOAT", r"\d+\.\d+")
        lexer.add("INTEGER", r"\d+")
        lexer.add("PLUS", r"\+")
        lexer.add("MINUS", r"-")
        lexer.add("MUL", r"\*")
        lexer.add("DIV", r"/")
        lexer.add("OPEN_PARENS", r"\(")
        lexer.add("CLOSE_PARENS", r"\)")
        lexer.add("PRINT", r"print")

        # Ignore spaces
        lexer.ignore(r"\s+")

        # Build the lexer
        self.lexer = lexer.build()

    def lex(self, text: str) -> LexerStream:
        return self.lexer.lex(text)


class Parser:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Create a parser
        pg = ParserGenerator(
            [
                "INTEGER",
                "FLOAT",
                "OPEN_PARENS",
                "CLOSE_PARENS",
                "PLUS",
                "MINUS",
                "MUL",
                "DIV",
                "PRINT",
            ],
            precedence=[("left", ["PLUS", "MINUS"]), ("left", ["MUL", "DIV"])],
        )

        @pg.production("print_statement : PRINT OPEN_PARENS expression CLOSE_PARENS")
        def print_statement(p: list[Token]) -> Print:
            # Print the result of what's inside the parenthesis
            return Print(p[2])

        @pg.production("expression : expression PLUS expression")
        @pg.production("expression : expression MINUS expression")
        @pg.production("expression : expression MUL expression")
        @pg.production("expression : expression DIV expression")
        def expression(p: list[Token]) -> BinaryOp:
            left = p[0]
            operator = p[1]
            right = p[2]
            if operator.gettokentype() == "PLUS":
                return Add(left, right)
            elif operator.gettokentype() == "MINUS":
                return Sub(left, right)
            elif operator.gettokentype() == "MUL":
                return Mul(left, right)
            elif operator.gettokentype() == "DIV":
                return Div(left, right)
            else:
                raise AssertionError("Oops, this should not be possible!")

        @pg.production("expression : INTEGER")
        def expression_integer(p: list[Token]) -> Number:
            return Number(int(p[0].value))

        @pg.production("expression : FLOAT")
        def expression_float(p: list[Token]) -> Number:
            return Number(float(p[0].value))

        @pg.error
        def error_handle(token: Token) -> None:
            raise ValueError(token)

        self.pg = pg.build()

    def parse(self, tokens: LexerStream) -> BaseBox:
        return self.pg.parse(tokens)


class Number(BaseBox):
    def __init__(self, value: int | float):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return self.value


class BinaryOp(BaseBox):
    def __init__(self, left: Token, right: Token) -> None:
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class Add(BinaryOp):
    def eval(self) -> int | float:
        left_value: int | float = self.left.eval()
        right_value: int | float = self.right.eval()
        return left_value + right_value


class Sub(BinaryOp):
    def eval(self):
        return self.left.eval() - self.right.eval()


class Mul(BinaryOp):
    def eval(self):
        return self.left.eval() * self.right.eval()


class Div(BinaryOp):
    def eval(self):
        return self.left.eval() / self.right.eval()


class Print(BaseBox):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        print(self.value.eval())


text_input = """
print(4 + 4 - 2)
"""

lexer = Lexer()
tokens = lexer.lex(text_input)

parser = Parser()
parser.parse(tokens).eval()
```